# Not able to start a pod in minikube by pulling image from external private registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have an ubuntu installed on my laptop.

I started a private docker registry (ssl enabled + htpasswd secured) and added it on overlay network (so it can be accessed from other hosts/vms)

here is the code (docker-compose.yaml):

```
version: "3"

services:
 registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/domain.crt
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/domain.key
    REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
  volumes:
    - /certs:/certs
    - ~/caas_rd/workspace/ci_cd_pipeline/registry_setup:/auth
  networks:
    - overlaynetwork
networks:
  overlaynetwork:
```

so my registry is running in the following link (with dns, i can verify it in browser) : https://home-thinkpad-t420s:5000/v2/_catalog

Now I installed "Minikube" on my laptop. && ssh it by "minikube ssh".

I created a folder "/etc/docker/certs.d" on minikube vm & added certificates as per instructions :

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#understanding-the-configuration

I also modified /etc/hosts && appended ca.cert on /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.

and restarted docker service on minikube vm by : sudo systemctl restart docker.service

after this I am able to pull the images on minikube vm by "docker login & docker pull" & also by "curl with (cacert + username/password)"
above is working perfectly fine, means I can successfully access/pull private registry images inside minikube vm.

Then I tried to create a secret (on my laptop with kubectl create -f ) defined as below:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Secret"
metadata:
  name: "ssl-proxy-secret"
  namespace: "default"
data:
 proxycert: "LS0..."
 proxykey: "LS0t..."
 htpasswd: "YWRt..."
```

and created a pod (on my laptop with kubectl create -f ) defined as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-jenkins
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-jenkins-container
    image: home-thinkpad-t420s:5000/my-jenkins
    volumeMounts:
    - name: secrets
      mountPath: /etc/secrets
  volumes:
  - name: secrets
    secret:
       secretName: ssl-proxy-secret
```

but when I try to run this pod, it throws error :

Failed to pull image "home-thinkpad-t420s:5000/my-jenkins": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: image my-jenkins not found
Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "private-jenkins-container" with ErrImagePull: "rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: image my-jenkins not found"

If I am able to pull images inside the minikube vm successfully by curl & docker login/pull......then when why pod creation is failing with above error ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separated `kubernetes registry secret` instead. Could use this command:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <secret-name> \
--docker-email=<your-email> --docker-username=<registry-user> \
--docker-password=<registry-password> --docker-server=<registry-server-domain>
```

After that you could update the `pod configuration` as follow:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-jenkins
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-jenkins-container
    image: home-thinkpad-t420s:5000/my-jenkins
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: <secret-name>
```

Reference: [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove those double quotes escpecially from the credentials  in the secret.yml file and try spinning the pod again ?

Comment: what namespace is the pod in ? I assume default